# Python selenium selecting an invisible checkbox

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am trying to uncheck a checkbox using selenium in Python. However, I got the following error message:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException:
>   Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

I am wondering how should I make it visible?

An interesting part of this checkbox is that it contains some JavaScript, and I am not sure if this is the place caused the trouble. I tried the following methods but got the same error.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("1986 Thru 1990").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="1986 Thru 1990"]').click()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add some time to wait until element become visible:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'1986 Thru 1990')))
element.click()
```

Let me know if issue still persist

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But it looks like I got a timeout exception `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: `. Should I increase the timeout limit?

Comment: No. Tell me whether this check-box is initially visible or you need to scroll down to see it or to hover mouse pointer over it to make it visible?

Comment: @tao.hong if you got a timeout exception with this, then that might mean you're not grabbing the right element with your `xpath`. You're possibly getting some element that's not visible. Providing some html might help.

Comment: I can "see" the checkboxes without scrolling down the page in Chrome and Firebox. Here is the link:https://nepis.epa.gov/Exe/ZyNET.exe?User=anonymous&Password=anonymous&Client=EPA&Init=1&SearchBack=ZyActionL&SortMethod=h&SortMethod=-&MaximumDocuments=15&Display=hpfr&ImageQuality=r85g16%252Fr85g16%252Fx150y150g16%252Fi500&DefSeekPage=x&ZyAction=ZyActionE&Toc=&TocEntry=&QField=&QFieldYear=&QFieldMonth=&QFieldDay=&UseQField=&Docs=&IntQFieldOp=0&ExtQFieldOp=0&File=&SeekPage=&Back=ZyActionL&BackDesc=Contents+page&MaximumPages=1&ZyEntry=0&TocRestrict=n&SearchMethod=2&Time=&Query=&FuzzyDegree=0

Comment: @tao.hong looks like that `input` isn't actually the checkbox you see, try clicking the `label` since clicking that entire element checks the box. `"//label[@for='2011 Thru 2015']